# how to use filter function to show li?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to filter my `li` using `filter function` on change event of dropdown .I added the classes with name
`team-MI team-SRH`.If I select `Mumbai Indians` from dropdown .It should show only `Mumbai Indians` `li`.`Mumbai Indians`  has selected value is `MI` using that I want to filter my list.

can `filter` function do this.

here is my code
https://jsbin.com/laritakevi/edit?html,js,output

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>

  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<select id="patientType">
     <option value="All">All</option>

   <option value="MI">Mumbai Indians</option>
  <option value="SRH">Sunrisers Hyderabad</option>
  <option value="RCB">Royal Challengers Bangalore</option>
  <option value="GL">Gujarat Lions</option>
  <option value="RPS">Rising Pune Supergiant</option>
  <option value="KXIP">Kings XI Punjab</option>

  </select>

  <ul>
    <li itemscope="" itemprop="subEvent" class="team-MI team-SRH venue-Mumbai live">
        <div class="matchdetails">
            <div itemprop="performer" class="match-teams">Mumbai Indians vs Sunrisers Hyderabad</div>

        </div>
    </li>
    <li itemscope="" itemprop="subEvent" class="team-KKR team-KXIP venue-Kolkata">
        <div class="matchdetails">
            <div itemprop="performer" class="match-teams">Kolkata Knight Riders vs Kings XI Punjab</div>

        </div>
    </li>
    <li itemscope="" itemprop="subEvent" class="team-RCB team-MI venue-Bengaluru">
        <div class="matchdetails">
            <div itemprop="performer" class="match-teams">Royal Challengers Bangalore vs Mumbai Indians</div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li itemscope="" itemprop="subEvent" class="team-GL team-RPS venue-Rajkot">
        <div class="matchdetails">
            <div itemprop="performer" class="match-teams">Gujarat Lions vs Rising Pune Supergiant</div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li itemscope="" itemprop="subEvent" class="team-KKR team-SRH venue-Kolkata">
        <div class="matchdetails">
            <div itemprop="performer" class="match-teams">Kolkata Knight Riders vs Sunrisers Hyderabad</div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li itemscope="" itemprop="subEvent" class="team-DD team-KXIP venue-Delhi">
        <div class="matchdetails">
            <div itemprop="performer" class="match-teams">Delhi Daredevils vs Kings XI Punjab</div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li itemscope="" itemprop="subEvent" class="team-MI team-GL venue-Mumbai">
        <div class="matchdetails">
            <div itemprop="performer" class="match-teams">Mumbai Indians vs Gujarat Lions</div>
        </div>
    </li>

</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){
  var arr=[];
      //all li
    console.log($('ul li'))
$('#patientType').on("change",function() {
   //Your code here
  console.log(this.value );
  $('ul li').filter(function(item){
    console.log($(item).attr('class').indexOf(this.value))
    return $(item).attr('class').indexOf(this.value) != -1
  })
});  
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need to use .filter()? I usually solve these cases, by hiding all elements and then showing the ones with matching criteria. This case by class 'team-' + value of the input.

Here is working JavaScript for the particular case;

```
$(function(){

  $('#patientType').on("change",function() {

    var val = $(this).val();
    $('ul li').hide();
    $('ul').find('.team-' + val).show();

  });  

});
```

This hides all list elements and then shows the ones with matching class.

Answer (score 0):

I think we can also use :

```
$(function(){
  $('#patientType').on("change",function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
     $('ul li').not('.team-' + val).hide();
  });  
});
```

I have not tried though.

Comment: Hi that solution will at the end hide all the list elements as it never shows any of them, only hides and hides. At some point you've hidden them all.